# Как изменить внешний вид программы C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, поиск-библиотек

Как можно изменить "тему" программы? Какие есть бесплатные решения и вообще способы?

Comment: какой "программы"?

Comment: Если речь идёт о WPF: cпособ-то понятен, замените стиль по умолчанию для каждого из контролов. Работы многовато выйдет. Где-то были бесплатные наборы стилей, не уверен насчёт их качества.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @Stack, WinForms

Comment: @VladD, я так понимаю что и для winforms можно вручную все переопределить, но это какой-то рабский труд, имхо.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Если речь идёт о WinForms, там вроде бы достаточно слабые возможности кастомизации :-\ Но я не эксперт в WinForms, подождём, пока подтянутся эксперты.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите набор компонентов [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/skins/).
Довольно неплохой набор тем, которые применимы не только к форме приложения, но и к другим компонентам пакета. Но, к сожалению, он не бесплатен.